# Algerbraic manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm sure this will be simple for someone, how do you go from the line I've highlighted (with the oversized arrow) to the next line. I can't see it.
[image: Question]

Thanks
Mike

Comment: That's only linearity of the integral: for any two integrable function $\;f,\,g\;$ , we have $$\int(f(x)+g(x))dx=\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$$

Comment: Just notice $\frac{e^{2x}+1-e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}=\frac{(e^{2x}+1)-e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}=\frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}+1}-\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$I = \int (\frac {e^{2x}+1 - e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}) \mathrm {d}x $$ $$= \int (\frac {e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}+1} - \frac {e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}) \mathrm {d}x $$ $$= \int (1 - \frac {e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}) \mathrm {d}x $$

The fact that we can rearrange the terms and cancel out common terms is used here. Hope it helps.